# GridView Color flutter algorithm

Tags: algorithm, flutter, gridview

I have a gridview that has two columns, and I want to have a different color in each row. For example, the first row needs to be white, the second grey, third white, fourth grey etc. Which basically means that elements with index 0,1,4,5,8,9 etc should have white, while the others 2,3,6,7,10 etc should be grey. I fail to find the algorithmic thought needed for my color control.

[image]

Comment: `(i ~/ 2).isEven`

Comment: this indeed works! thanks, although I fail to understand why, could you explain it as an answer, so I can also mark it as correct?

Comment: `for (int i=0; i<10; i++) print('$i -> ${i ~/ 2}  -> ${(i ~/ 2).isEven}');`